# can't compile java error variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java

i can't compile this program, i try to make overriding program and get an error. if i deleted new tes2(kata, key); to new tes2(); error again , java:21: error: constructor tes2 in class tes2 cannot be applied to given types; help please! sorry for my bad english

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class mod2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    String kata;
    int key;
    System.out.print("          PROGRAM CAESARCHIPER  \n");


    tes1 obj = new tes1();
    tes2 objj = new tes2(kata, key);
    obj.inputt();
    objj.inputt();
    objj.asd();
    }
  }

class tes1 {

DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

public void inputt() throws IOException{

System.out.print("Input Kata = ");
String kata=input.readLine();

}
}

class tes2 extends tes1{
public String kata;
public int key;

public tes2(String kata, int key){
    this.kata=kata;
    this.key=key;
}

public void inputt() throws IOException{
    System.out.print("Key Encrypt = ");
    int key=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
}

public void inputt1()throws IOException{
    super.inputt();
}

public void asd(){
    String hasil = "" ;
    for(int i = 0; i < kata.length() ; i++)
    {
        int ascii = kata.charAt(i);
        int cipher = ascii + key ;
        hasil = hasil + (char)cipher;
    }
    System.out.println("Kata Yang Telah Di Encrypt = " + hasil );

}
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You do not hav a constructor in class tes2 with no arguments.

Comment: provide constructor in your class

Comment: Be nice. Indent your code properly if you are asking people to read it.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i'm a newbie. i don't know. :(

Answer (score 1):

In java, local variable must be initialized.

Replace :

```
String kata;
    int key;
```

With

```
 String kata = null;
    int key = 0;
```

Comment: thankyou, but now i got error again. 

Input Kata = sfd
Key Encrypt = 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tes2.asd(mod2.java:62)
 at mod2.main(mod2.java:26)

Process completed.

Comment: this is simple.change your method public void asd() to public void asd(String kata).And them method call must be objj.asd(kata);.And also your two method obj.inputt();
    objj.inputt1(); must have return type and accept this return data in your main method.

Comment: obj.inputt(); objj.inputt1(); must have return type and accept this return data in your main method.

i'm sorry, but how to make a returntype and return data? i'm a newbie sorry.

Comment: your code have other errors.so how i was modify and how can i give complete code to you?

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `String kata; int key;` dont hold values when you call the constructor `tes2 objj = new tes2(kata, key);` for example `kata="kata"; key=1` will work. In your code call the inputt and inputt1 mehtodes befor you call the constructor